# If $C=M \times [0,1]$, what is an integral over $\partial C$?

Tags: integration, definition

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Define $C=M \times [0,1]$ so that $\partial C = M \times \{0\} \cup M \times \{1\}$.

If $f:\partial C \to \mathbb{R}$, is then the integral over $\partial C$ of $f$ defined as
$$\int_{\partial C}f = \int_M f(\cdot, 0) + \int_M f(\cdot, 1)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is integration over a manifold with boundary that we are looking at here. Hence, you should be integrating a differential $ n $-form over $ \partial C $, where $ n = \dim(M) $. A smooth function $ f: \partial C \to \Bbb{R} $ is only a differential $ 0 $-form, so your expression is well-defined if and only if $ M $ is $ 0 $-dimensional. This means that $ M $ is a finite set of points, as you have assumed $ M $ to be compact. If you want to know how to integrate a differential $ n $-form, please refer to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

**Note:** You need to assume that $ M $ is oriented in order to do integration in the manner explained by the Wikipedia article; otherwise you need to use the concept of a **density**.

As a working example, suppose that $ M $ is a finite collection of points. Then for any smooth function $ f: C \to \Bbb{R} $, we have
$$
\int_{\partial C} f = \sum_{p \in M} [f(p,1) - f(p,0)],
$$
where the natural orientation of $ [0,1] $ is being used.

Now, the definition of the boundary of a manifold (with boundary) requires that the boundary be a subset of the manifold itself. Hence, it would be preferable if you write $ C = M \times [0,1] $. I suppose that you were thinking of the **topological boundary** of $ M \times (0,1) $ inside $ M \times \Bbb{R} $.

Comment: Thanks but I find the Wiki article very confusing mainly as I am versed in differential geometry so much.  Are you saying that what I wrote in the OP is true if $C = M \times [0,1]$? And that if $C=M \times (0,1)$ then $\partial C$ is not the same as $M \times \{0\} \cup M \times \{1\}$?

Comment: For **topological** manifolds, we have
$$
\partial(M \times N) = (\partial(M) \times N) \cup (M \times \partial(N)).
$$
Hence, if we assume that $ \partial(M) = \varnothing $, then
\begin{align}
\partial(M \times (0,1))
& = (\partial(M) \times (0,1)) \cup (M \times \partial((0,1))) \\
& = (\varnothing \times (0,1)) \cup (M \times \varnothing) \\
& = \varnothing.
\end{align}

Comment: However,
\begin{align}
\partial(M \times [0,1])
& = (\partial(M) \times [0,1]) \cup (M \times \partial([0,1])) \\
& = (\varnothing \times [0,1]) \cup (M \times \{ 0,1 \}) \\
& = M \times \{ 0,1 \} \\
& = (M \times \{ 0 \}) \cup (M \times \{ 1 \}).
\end{align}

Comment: For **differentiable** manifolds, which are what we’re dealing with, we have
$$
\partial(M \times N) = M \times \partial(N)
$$
if $ \partial(M) = \varnothing $. Hence, if your compact Riemannian manifold $ M $ is assumed to have no boundary, then
$$
   \partial(M \times (0,1))
= M \times \partial((0,1))
= M \times \varnothing
= \varnothing,
$$
whereas
$$
   \partial(M \times [0,1])
= M \times \partial([0,1])
= M \times \{ 0,1 \}
= (M \times \{ 0 \}) \cup (M \times \{ 1 \}).
$$

Comment: Note that ‘$ \partial $’ has two meanings. If we interpret ‘$ \partial $’ as the subspace-boundary operator, then we need to specify an **ambient space**. In the OP, you assumed the ambient space to be $ M \times \Bbb{R} $, which yields $ {\partial_{M \times \Bbb{R}}}(M \times (0,1)) = M \times \{ 0,1 \} $. If you assumed the ambient space to be $ M \times (0,1) $ itself, then $ {\partial_{M \times (0,1)}}(M \times (0,1)) = \varnothing $.

Comment: If we instead interpret ‘$ \partial $’ as the manifold-boundary operator, then we don’t need to specify an ambient space. By the formulas given above, we have $ \partial(M \times (0,1)) = \varnothing $ and $ \partial(M \times [0,1]) = M \times \{ 0,1 \} $.

Comment: OK, I definitely do not want to use ambient space and I mean $C=M \times [0,1]$ as a differential manifold.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, and my answer explains why you cannot integrate $ f $ over $ \partial(C) $. As $ \partial(C) $ is a differentiable $ n $-manifold, you can only integrate a differential $ n $-form on it, which $ f $ (being a function) is not, unless $ M $ is a finite collection of points.

Comment: Ok, so you say (and other sources say) that on a compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, only $n$ forms can be integrated and not functions. 

If I understand correctly, $L^p$ spaces on a Riemannian manifold $M$ are defined as the set of all function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_M |f|^pdV < \infty$, where $dV$ is the Riemannian volume form. This integral makes sense because the Riemannian volume form is an $n$-form. So then why don't we just define $\int_M f := \int_M fdV$? I'd assumed it was a given that the natural Riemannian volume form was the thing we are integrating wrt.

Comment: (Let's jus tassume $M$ is orientable).

Comment: Maybe with this clarification everything  makes sense.

Comment: @Chris: Hi Chris. You can certainly let $ \displaystyle \int_{M} f \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \int_{M} f ~ \mathrm{d}{V} $, but then, $ f ~ \mathrm{d}{V} $ itself is a differential $ n $-form because the volume form is a differential $ n $-form. Hence, your post would be much clearer if you had specified that integration was to be done with respect to a volume form, in which case your formula is correct. :) I apologize for taking you on a detour through differential forms — $ \displaystyle \int_{M} f $ can be interpreted in two different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. No I am glad you took the "detour" because it's helpful to build knowledge!